# Multiple row database into array (dropPin)

Tags: php

**PROBLEM**

As mentioned above. I have an example of code as shown below.

```
$mapItems = array(
    array("id" => 1, "title" => "map pin 1", "xcoord" => "420", "ycoord" => "120"),
    array("id" => 2, "title" => "map pin 2", "xcoord" => "429", "ycoord" => "129"),
    array("id" => 3, "title" => "map pin 3", "xcoord" => "329", "ycoord" => "329")
);
```

The problem is, I want to take the data from database and put into an array as shown above. I've tried and I don't know how it works. Below are some of my code:

```
$mapItems = array();
$qry='SELECT l.loc_x, l.loc_y, m.member_name '.
     'FROM location l '.
     'JOIN member m ON m.member_id = l.member_id '.
     "WHERE l.map_id = '$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $qry);
$tempNo=1;
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $mapItems["id"] = $tempNo;
    $mapItems["title"] = $rows['member_name'];
    $mapItems["xcoord"] = $rows['loc_x'];
    $mapItems["ycoord"] = $rows['loc_y'];
    $tempNo++;
}
```

I want to make my bottom code, looks exactly like the top code but by reading the data from database. Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

Finally I manage to get solution for my problem.

```
$qry='SELECT l.loc_x, l.loc_y, m.member_name '.
     'FROM location l '.
     'JOIN member m ON m.member_id = l.member_id '.
     "WHERE l.map_id = '$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $qry);
$i=1;
$mapItems = array();
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $loc = array("id"     => $i, 
                 "title"  => $rows['member_name'],
                 "xcoord" => $rows['loc_x'],
                 "ycoord" => $rows['loc_y']);
    $mapItems[] = $loc;
    $i++;
}
```

Reference: [dropPin](https://github.com/duncanheron/dropPin)

Comment: the problem here is that you adding all elements in the same index, for instance you are trying to fill the divided box `array` and alway you are put your clothes in the same box leaving the others empty .

Comment: @HassanAhmed Yes, I want to make my bottom code so that it can appears like the above code. I might have problem on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$i = 0; //array index
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $mapItems[$i]["id"] = $tempNo;
  $mapItems[$i]["title"] = $rows['member_name'];
  $mapItems[$i]["xcoord"] = $rows['loc_x'];
  $mapItems[$i]["ycoord"] = $rows['loc_y'];
  $tempNo++;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code. But same, the pin coordinate are not on the image as shown => [Image](http://imgur.com/abvg76Q)

Comment: Can you please post print_r($mapItems); array ?

Comment: It shows like this Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 1 [] => 322.6999969482422 ) [1] => Array ( [1] => 2 [] => 380.6999969482422 ) )

Comment: You must get keys like id,title,xcoord,ycoord in sub array. where are these?

Comment: foreach!! but here is while loop. anyway, can you show your foreach() code?

Comment: Wait, I don't understand =.=" I thought my code (bottom) will act as the mapItems code (top). So, I just combine my code (bottom) and the foreach (top).

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you

```
$qry="SELECT l.loc_x, l.loc_y, m.member_name FROM location l JOIN member m ON m.member_id = l.member_id WHERE l.map_id = '$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $qry);

$mapItems = array();
$tempNo=1;
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $mapItems[] = $row;
}
print_r($mapItems);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code. But the pin coordinate are not on the image, as shown => [Image](http://imgur.com/abvg76Q)

Comment: The coordinates is on the loc_x and loc_y. I want to make my code exactly like the top code, but the data are read from database.